# unexpected exception java.math.BigDecimal running on IBM WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, nullpointerexception, bigdecimal

Running Java application on IBM WebSphere caused such exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.math.BigDecimal.add2DFP(BigDecimal.java:1946)
at java.math.BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.java:1881)
at com.somepackage.components.view.PremiumSummaryViewModel.setPremiums(PremiumSummaryViewModel.java:101)
```

Null check is done. As I reviewed **java.math.BigDecimal** class has no such method **add2DFP** and does not call one either. Maybe it's specific to IBM's JDK.

Any comment on this would be appreciated.

Providing code regarding to exception

```
    BigDecimal annualPremiumAmt = nwtPremium != null && nwtPremium.getAnnualAmt() != null ? nwtPremium.getAnnualAmt() : BigDecimal.ZERO;
    if (nwtPremium != null) {
        BigDecimal formPremiumAmt = nwtPremium.getAnnualAmt();
        if (formPremiumAmt != null) {
            policyFormTotal = policyFormTotal.add(annualPremiumAmt); //Bigdecimal
            formList.setFormPremiumAmt(formList.getFormPremiumAmt().add(annualPremiumAmt)); //101 line
        }
    }
```

Instance is running on IBM JDK 1.6.

Comment: Showing the block of code where this is being generated would be very useful, especially the setting of the variables in question

Comment: If a string is being converted to BigDecimal, it would be helpful to see the string as well.

Comment: The IBM JVM has had encoding related problems in the past with BigDecimal. Please don't feed it anything else besides latin.

Comment: How do you know there is no such method called add2DFP. It is likely a private method. You can decompile and see that one such exists. If the method did not exist you would receive a different error (likely java.lang.NoSuchMethodError).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

Actually this whole expression is inside the loop that I thought was unnecessary to mention. I have moved declaration of **BigDecimal annualPremiumAmt** before the loop and reorganized code:

```
BigDecimal annualPremiumAmt;
for(...) { 

    if (nwtPremium) {
        annualPremiumAmt = nwtPremium.getAnnualAmt() != null ? nwtPremium.getAnnualAmt() : BigDecimal.ZERO;
        policyFormTotal = policyFormTotal.add(annualPremiumAmt);
        formList.setFormPremiumAmt(formList.getFormPremiumAmt().add(annualPremiumAmt));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would submit your issues to IBM Software Support.  They don't charge per instance, it's unlimited amount of requests as long as you have a support agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Is policyFormTotal NULL? How about the result of formList.getFormPremiumAmt()?
You never check those in this code block.

Comment: policyFormTotal was not null.